# Set a Variable in a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to pass declared variables to build my string.  I think I want to set my variable via a case expression but I have not done this before.  Here is what I have done thus far.

```
 DECLARE  @stu_conv  AS VARCHAR(5)

 -- I think I need a select here.
 set @stu_conv = CASE  WHEN ITMMASTER.STU_0 ='KG' THEN'2.2'END

 SELECT
 YPRIMAT.YCROPYR_0
    ,ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0
    ,SPRICLIST.DCGVAL_3
    ,ITMMASTER.TSICOD_2
    ,ITMMASTER.ACCCOD_0
    ,(BASPRI_0*@stu_conv)  AS ImportstringAS Importstring
FROM LIVE.YPRIMAT
   INNER JOIN LIVE.ITMMASTER ON YPRIMAT.ITMREF_0 = ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
   LEFT OUTER JOIN LIVE.SPRICLIST ON ITMMASTER.TCLCOD_0 = SPRICLIST.PLICRI1_0
   WHERE SPRICLIST.PLICRD_0 = 'SPL000020'
```

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point for using a variable here, and trying to set it outside the query does not make sense, since you most likely want the value to reset for each row.

I would suggest moving the `case` expression *into* the query, as follows:

```
select
    y.ycropyr_0,
    i.tclcod_0,
    s.dcgval_3,
    i.tsicod_2,
    i.acccod_0,
    baspri_0 * case when i.stu_0 = 'KG' then 2.2 else 1 end as importstringas importstring
from live.yprimat y
inner join live.itmmaster i on y.itmref_0 = i.itmref_0
left outer join live.spriclist s on i.tclcod_0 = s.plicri1_0
where s.plicrd_0 = 'SPL000020'
```

I assumed that you want a value of `1` when `stu_0` is *not* `'KG'`, but you can change this as needed.

Side note:

- I modified your query to use table aliases. This makes the query shorter to write and somehow easier to read
- you would need to prefix column `baspri_0` with the table it belongs to (as your query is, it is not possible to tell)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're declaring a string and then multiplying it, but I would just inline the case (and add a default case?):

```
,(BASPRI_0 * CASE 
             WHEN ITMMASTER.STU_0 ='KG' 
             THEN 2.2
             ELSE ???
             END)  AS Importstring
```